# What causes buttons to turn blue in IE when you mouseover?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have an application with a number of buttons in various places.
In IE only, I have noticed that most of the buttons turn blue when you mouse over them, but not all the buttons.

So, two part question:

1. What is causing them to turn blue? I have tried many searches to figure out who is actually doing this , but apparently I am not choosing the correct search terms. Can someone give me a hint that will get me to the right place, so that I can research the answer to my second question:
2. Why would some buttons not turn blue? Once I figure out who is doing this, I am hoping I will be able to understand how I have managed to create some buttons where this doesn't happen, but if anyone happens to have any clues, they would be gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why they are turning blue.

But every browser has a default style for html elements. So, thats why it might look different in a different browser.

Its a common practice now to have a CSS reset as the top level CSS file.

I would google HTML reset or HTML5 reset.  What this CSS reset does is make a style for every HTML element and applies a default style.

So, that your styles will look consistent across every browser.